# Find last modified file to match simple wildcard regex expression in directory

Tags: regex, bash, grep, find

I'm working in a linux environment and I need to find the last modified file to match a simple regex. For example:

```
testname_20150328.csv #Last modified 2015-05-12
testname_20150501.csv #Last modified 2015-05-01
testname_20140328.csv #Last modified 2014-03-28
notamatch.csv
alsonotamatch.csv
```

So the pattern in this situation will be "testname_*.csv". I'm ignoring the value of the wildcard and just pulling the last modified file from the folder. I would want the output of my request to be something like

```
./testname_20150328.csv
```

The main problem I have been having I have been running commands like

```
ls -p -t . | grep -v / | head -1
```

which gives me the last modified file, but doesnt filter out files according to the regex, or

```
find -name "testname_*.csv"
```

which matches the regex, but doesnt let me get details about last modified times. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Try `ls -p -t testname_*.csv | head -1`

Comment: And of course it's that simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Costas posted the answer I was too blind to see,

```
ls -p -t testname_*.csv | head -1
```

Which is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for *any* legal file name, including those containing newlines (which precludes parsing the output of `ls`):

```
max_mod_time=0
for f in testname_*.csv; do
    last_mod_time=$(stat -c %Y "$f")
    [ "$last_mod_time" -gt "$max_mod_time" ] || continue

    last_mod_time=$max_mod_time
    last_mod=$f
done
```

The exact invocation of `stat` may vary (GNU `stat` shown), as it is not covered by the POSIX specification.